# How to transition from using Google Sheets as a database? (Needs to be manually updated by non tech employees)

Tags: python, database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am currently trying to help a small business transition from using Google Sheets as a database to something more robust and scalable - preferably staying within Google services. I've looked into Google Cloud Storage and BigQuery, however - there are employees that need to manually update new data so anything in GCP won't be user friendly for non technical persons. I was thinking of employees still manually updating the Google sheets, and write a Python program to automatically update GCS or BigQuery, but the issue is that Google sheets is extremely slow and cannot handle the amount of data that's currently stored in there now.

Has anyone faced a similar issue and have any ideas/suggestions? Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

What you might be able to do is to save the Google Sheet file as a .csv file and then [import it in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv). From there, maybe the employes can use simple commands to [insert data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_examples). Please note that this question is very opinion based and anyone can suggest various ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes I agree it’s an open ended opinion based question, there could be many different ways to approach it and I’m open to hearing any of them. Thank you for your ideas and response! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a web app hosted on App engine for the front end and data entry and connect it to Cloud SQL or BQ as a backend. You can create a UI in your web app where employees can access data from CloudSQL/BQ if needed. Alternatively you can use Google forms for data entry and connect it to Cloud SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! One of my ideas was similar to yours, but I thought there might have been a more simple way to go about it. This may be better in the long run though as the company grows. Thanks again :)

Comment: No worries. Just an additional note that you do not necessarily have to use GCP to do this. There are open source alternatives for your use case.

Comment: Would you mind pointing me in the right direction or maybe post a link to an example open source alternative? Thanks again!